# How to use Netty clients within Netty server

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, netty

I'm going to create an authentication server which itself interacts with 
a set of different Oauth2.0 servers.
Netty seems to be a good candidate to implement network part here.
But before start I need to clear some details about netty as I'm new to it.
The routine will be as follows:

1. The server accepts an HTTPS connection from a client.
2. Then, not closing this first connection, it makes another connection
   via HTTPS to a remote Oauth2.0 server and gets data
3. After all, the server sends the result back to the client which is supposed to keep the connection alive.

How to implement this scenario with Netty?
Do I have to create a new netty client and/or reconnect it each time I need to connect to a remote Oauth2.0 server?
If so, I'll have to create a separate thread for every 
outgoing connection which will drastically reduce performance.
Another scenario is to create a sufficient number of Netty clients 
within a server at the beginning (when server starts)
and keep them constantly connected to the Oauth2.0 servers via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

That's easily done with Netty. First you set up your Netty server using the `ServerBootstrap` and then in a `ChannelHandler` that handles your connection from the client you can use e.g. the client `Bootstrap` to connect to the OAuth server and fetch the data. You don't need to worry about creating threads or similar. You can do it all in a non-blocking fashion. Take a look at and try to understand how this example works:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.java#L44.